# Collections annotated with @ElementCollection in an entity is not parsed to SQL when using a Query created by EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, jpa-2.1

In a JPA project, there is an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Explanation {
    //other fields
    private Set<Sentence> sentences = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "sentence")
    @AttributeOverride(name="sentence", column=@Column(name = "sentence", nullable = false))
    public Set<Sentence> getSentences() {
    return sentences;
    }

    public void setSentences(Set<Sentence> sentences) {
    this.sentences = sentences;
    }
    //there are other setters and getters as well
}
```

where the `Sentence` class is annotated with `@Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
public class Sentence {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private final String sentence;

    public Sentence(String sentence) {
    this.sentence = sentence;
    }

    public String getSentence() {
    return sentence;
    }

}
```

The entity can be parsed into a table successfully and the `@Embeddable Sentence` class is also parsed into a table through automatically generated SQL:

```
create table sentence (Explanation_id bigint not null, sentence varchar(255) not null, primary key (Explanation_id, sentence)) engine=InnoDB
```

**Problem:** When querying the `Explanation` entities by means of a `Query` with `EntityManager`:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Explanation e WHERE e.lexicalItem.language = :fromLanguage AND e.language = :toLanguage AND e.lexicalItem.value = :value",
            Explanation.class)
            .setParameter("fromLanguage", lexicalItemVO.language())
            .setParameter("toLanguage", toLanguage)
            .setParameter("value", lexicalItemVO.value())
            .getResultList();
```

It fails with the following error:

```
19:49:57,349 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) (conn=6) Unknown column 'e1_0.sentences' in 'field list'
19:49:57,353 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.DefaultExceptionMapper] (default task-2) RESTEASY002375: Error processing request GET /dictionary/rest/vocabularies/en;explanation_language=en/take - rx.dictionary.rest.VocabulariesResource.getExplanations: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : JDBC exception executing SQL [select e1_0.id,e1_0.creation_date,e1_0.explanation,e1_0.language,e1_0.last_update_time,e1_0.item_id,e1_0.partOfSpeech,e1_0.sentences from explanation e1_0 join lexical_item l1_0 on l1_0.id=e1_0.item_id where l1_0.language=? and e1_0.language=? and l1_0.value=?]
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:374)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1032)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94)
    at deployment.dictionary.war//rx.dictionary.ExplanationRepository.find(ExplanationRepository.java:36)
    at deployment.dictionary.war//rx.dictionary.rest.VocabulariesService.findExplanations(VocabulariesService.java:53)
    at deployment.dictionary.war//rx.dictionary.rest.VocabulariesService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.findExplanations$$super(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:78)
    at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:197)
    at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:185)
    at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:53)
    at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:90)
    at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
    at deployment.dictionary.war//rx.dictionary.rest.VocabulariesService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.findExplanations(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.dictionary.war//rx.dictionary.rest.VocabulariesResource.getExplanations(VocabulariesResource.java:35)
    at deployment.dictionary.war//rx.dictionary.rest.VocabulariesResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getExplanations(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.undertow.websocket@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:172)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.smallrye.opentracing-contrib//io.smallrye.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:69)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@3.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@3.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@3.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:391)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.8.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select e1_0.id,e1_0.creation_date,e1_0.explanation,e1_0.language,e1_0.last_update_time,e1_0.item_id,e1_0.partOfSpeech,e1_0.sentences from explanation e1_0 join lexical_item l1_0 on l1_0.id=e1_0.item_id where l1_0.language=? and e1_0.language=? and l1_0.value=?]
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:253)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.lambda$processNext$0(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advance(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:274)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:142)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:102)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:305)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:546)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=6) Unknown column 'e1_0.sentences' in 'field list'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:282)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:370)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.message.ClientMessage.readPacket(ClientMessage.java:134)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readPacket(StandardClient.java:883)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResults(StandardClient.java:822)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResponse(StandardClient.java:741)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:665)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:291)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.9.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:217)
    ... 124 more
```